# Kinect v2 SDK 2.0 How to Save Multiple Skeleton Subjects to File

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

My question is pretty straightforward.
I can save all streams of `Kinect v2 (and Kinect v1)` synchronized. If I also have skeleton for one person, skeleton information is also saved.

My issue now is that I want to save the same synchronized information (color, depth, infrared, bodyindex and skeleton), but for the maximum of 6 people. 
I think this can be accomplished by one of two ways:

Solution 1) - create one skeleton file for each of the 6 people, using the ID as reference for the filename, for instance.

Solution 2) - saved all this information in one single file, as I do for the remaining streams, using again an ID before each new person.

Besides, anyone has any clue on how to "lock" each person ID using `Kinect SDK 2.0`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create Single File for each person.Then you can alter the contents very easily.If you are adding all the details in a single file,it will make the code complex.

Comment: Well, I also think it's the "cleanest" solution - the issue regarding this is the lock on subject matter...

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would save the data under a single INI or XML file using the persons ID to create the section they are referenced by. This will help reduce the complexity of your code if you use an online library. This will allow for greater extensibility and offer you the ability to edit two profiles at once without having to open multiple files.

As for 'locking' the user to an ID, that isn't something the Kinect itself is capable of. In order to do that you would have to create an algorithm that assigns an ID based on information about the user. To create an ID with staying power you need to make your program reliably be able to assign a unique signifier based on something like facial recognition, body size, name and/or distinguishing characteristics. The ID would have to be system independent, meaning that the same ID would be ascribed to that person regardless of if the computer running the program has seen them before. This would allow you to not only keep track of someone who leaves the screen, but between systems. This, however, is very difficult to coordinate and there is very little middle ground in making a system able to know that the person walking back into frame is the same. The Kinect DOES do this, but it uses xbox accounts as its unique identifier, something that the SDK does not allow you to utilize.
(TL;DR You would have to make your own version of xbox accounts and your own identifying system for those accounts using the SDK)